# Java: como pausar dentro del actionPerformed

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenos días/tardes/noches, últimamente he tenido problemas en encontrar una solución para mi problema
lo que intento hacer es pausar un programa de java, esto lo solía hacer en C con **sleep(milisegundos);** y funcionaba como yo deseaba ya que el momento de espera se realizaba después de la instrucción que va antes del sleep pero aquí en java he tenido problemas
he tratado con **Thread.sleep(milisegundos)** y como lo uso dentro del actionPerformed resulta que el tiempo de espera se aplica antes de ejecutar el método, cosa que no quiero.
Me gustaría saber si hay una forma de aplicar la pausa en el lugar que deseo, este es mi código:

```
if(aux1.getIcon().toString().equals("f.jpg"))
    aux1.setIcon(img[id]);
else
    aux1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("f.jpg"));

if(turnos%2==0)
{
    // Justo aquí es donde quiero la pausa, que lo de abajo tarde en realizarse.

    if(aux1.getName().equals(aux2.getName()))
    {
        aux1.setVisible(false);
        aux2.setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        aux1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("f.jpg"));
        aux2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("f.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar porque en verdad no encuentro alguna solución para este problema que tengo.

Answer (score 1):

Java procesa todos los eventos de ratón y teclado en un hilo aparte conocido como hilo de despacho de eventos (EDT Event dispatch Thread). Llamar a `Thread.sleep(milisegundos);`evita que la UI se actualice. Te aconsejo que emplees un [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) para lo que deseas hacer.